# CakePHP 2.0.X routing trouble

Tags: cakephp, routes, bancha

I put the following codes into routes.php file.

```
Router::parseExtensions('js');
Router::connect('/bancha-api.js?models=*', array('controller' => 'Bancha', 'action' => 'index'));
```

I want to visit "localhost/Bancha-cakephp/bancha-api.js" in browser, and it can go to Bancha/index instead.(Bancha-cakephp is subfolder holding all CakePHP files).

But got

> Error: The requested address '/Bancha-cakephp/bancha-api.js' was not found on this server.

Anybody can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just come across your question. In the future just use [GitHub for Bug Reports](https://github.com/Bancha/Bancha/issues) and the [Sencha Forums for Questions](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141983-Bancha-Combining-CakePHP-and-ExtJS).

The following error resulted because of an API change inside a CakePHP stable release and is already fixed in Bancha Projects current release.

Best regards,
Roland

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable debug level 2 in `core.php`, then you will know what does trigger this error.

In production mode (debug=0), Cakephp will send 404 Not found errors to many requests.

But if you switch to development mode (debug=2), then you should get a more helping error message like `"Missing controller"`

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the Router connection without the query:

```
Router::connect('/bancha-api.js', array('controller' => 'Bancha', 'action' => 'index'));
```

You can access and process the "models" query string parameter inside the action.